# ADT. Change project location

Tags: android, cordova, adt

I have an android APP which uses phonegap.

/myprojects/MyAppv1/... (phonegap 2.6.0 repository)

I've upgraded to PhoneGap 3.3.0 and generated a new repository :

/myprojects/MyAppv2/...

Now, when I want to import the new project (File > New Project > Android Project From Existing Code), ADT tells me "Cannot import MyApp because the project name is in use".

How can I tell ADT to use the new repertory instead of the old one ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should go to 'myprojects' folder and rename the old folder name to another name,
then make import again.

The value in the field 'New Project Name' in import window inside eclipse is the folder name of the project, so it shouldn't exist already, if the folder already exist rename it in your working directory.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. When I move the current directory to MyAppV1_old and launch ADT again, ADT comes with a screen telling me "Resource 'MyApp/.project' does not exist. If I try "File > Import" with the contents of /myprojects/MyAppv2/ I get the "Cannot import MyApp because the project name is in use" again.

Answer (score 1):

`File>Import`.When importing change name of the project under New Project Name, just click on the name to select it.

[image]

Comment: Same result. I get the "Cannot import MyApp because the project name is in use" message

Answer (score 0):

Although the application names are different(such as Myapp1, Myapp2), the project name which is chosen could be same.

As Mahmoud said, there is only reason behind the error

- Other applications(Even Myapp1) can also have the same project name as Myapp2.

Solution:

You can't change the project name of MyAppv2, before you are importing.

[image]

In this above picture, MainActivity is the name project which you already had. So, you should change the application name as 'mainActivity'.

After changing the name of the project, You can import your new Application.

Hope, it will be helpful.

Comment: The application name is the same in both directories. It's MyApp since it is the name of my Android App in Google Play.

Comment: @AlainZelink Do you want previous application too?

Comment: What I want to do is have 2 directories corresponding to 2 different versions of the same APP built with 2 different versions of PhoneGap. Since it corresponds to an App in Google Play, I need to keep the same App Name. But I want to be able to point to one directory or another. Or maybe there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: That's it ! Hourray ! Thank you for that. It seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I try remove all workspace folder manually (C://Users/[UserName>]/Workspace) and then I try to open project again (File -> New -> Project -> Android -> Android Project From Existing Code).
And I dont check (Copy project into workspace)
just Working now!